# Физическая и логическая адресация секторов SD карты

Tags: железо, fat32, sd, mbr

При попытке обратиться к нулевому сектору SDHC карты по SPI, например с помощью команды **CMD17 (READ_SINGLE_BLOCK)**, я обнаруживаю, что аргумент интерпретируется как **физический** адрес, в то время как MBR FAT32 расположен в нулевом **логическом**.

При этом физический нулевой сектор в большинстве случаев содержит последовательность

> { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 ..., 0x00, 0x55, 0xAA }

Как, в таком случае, следует определять, где расположена настоящая MBR, расположенная в нулевом **логическом** секторе?

[image: Снимок сканирования секторов SD карты с помощью программы WinHex]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё-таки нулевой **физический** сектор ЗУ с FAT32 представляет собой структуру [MBR](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C):

```
typedef struct
{
    // Программа IPL 1 (программа загрузчика занимает зону от адреса 00h до 1BEh)
    unsigned char nothing[446];

    // Таблица разделения физического диска на логические устройства (Partition Tables)
    // (4 строки по 16 байт = 64 байта) занимает зону с адреса 1BEh до 1FDh 
    unsigned char partitionData[64];

    // 2 последних байта в блоке данных сектора с адреса 1FE по 1FF - Ending Signature
    unsigned int signature; //0xAA55
    // 55АА - отмечает конец MBR. Проверяется программой начального загрузчика
} MBR_INFO_STRUCTURE;
```

(а не пустую последовательность 0x00, как мне показалось сначала).

В ней, в свою очередь, содержатся 4 [таблицы разделов](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C#.D0.A2.D0.B0.D0.B1.D0.BB.D0.B8.D1.86.D0.B0_.D1.80.D0.B0.D0.B7.D0.B4.D0.B5.D0.BB.D0.BE.D0.B2) (partition table), указывающих на **логические** разделы:

```
typedef struct
{       
    unsigned char status; // Флаг загрузки (0x80 - активный / 0x00 - обычный раздел) - 1 байт

    unsigned char headStart; // Начальный физический сектор раздела (головка) - 1 байт
    unsigned int cylSectStart; // Начальный физический сектор раздела (сектор и цилиндр) - 2 байта

    unsigned char type; // Код типа раздела - 1 байт

    unsigned char headEnd; // Конечный физический сектор раздела (головка) - 1 байт
    unsigned int cylSectEnd; // Конечный физический сектор раздела (сектор и цилиндр) - 2 байта

    unsigned long firstSector; // Число секторов предшествующих разделу - 4 байта
    unsigned long sectorsTotal; // Общее количество секторов в данном разделе - 4 байта
} PARTITION_INFO_16_BYTE_LINE;
```

Нулевой же **логический** сектор содержит структуру [BPB](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2_BIOS):

```
typedef struct
{
    unsigned char jumpBoot[3]; // Команды JMP и NOP // [0, 2]
    unsigned char OEMName[8]; // Название и версия ОС // [3, 10]

    // Эта часть загрузочного сектора известна как BIOS Parameter Block (BPB) (блок параметров BIOS).
    // Она содержит физические характеристики диска, которые MS-DOS и Windows используют при поиске определенного участка.
    // Складывая или перемножая значения этих параметров, операционная система узнает,
    // где находится таблица FAT, корневой каталог, где начинается и кончается область данных.

    // Формат блока параметров BIOS: DOS 7.1 EBPB (FAT32):

    // DOS 2.0 BPB
    unsigned int bytesPerSector; // Количество байтов на сектор // [11, 12]
    unsigned char sectorPerCluster; // Количество секторов на кластер (всегда кратно двум в степени n) // [13]
    unsigned int reservedSectorCount; // Количество зарезервированных секторов перед первой FAT // [14, 15]
    unsigned char numberofFATs; // Количество таблиц FAT // [16]
    unsigned int rootEntryCount; // Количество элементов в корневом каталоге (максимальный предел) // [17, 18]
    unsigned int totalSectors_F16; // Общее число секторов FAT16 // [19, 20]
    unsigned char mediaType; // Дескриптор среды // [21]
    unsigned int FATsize_F16; // Количество секторов на элемент таблицы FAT16 // [22, 23]

    // DOS 3.31 ВРВ
    unsigned int sectorsPerTrack; // Количество секторов на дорожку // [24, 25]
    unsigned int numberofHeads; // Число головок // [26, 27]
    unsigned long hiddenSectors; // Количество скрытых секторов // [28, 31]
    unsigned long totalSectors_F32; // Общее число секторов, если размер диска больше 32 Мб // [32, 35]

    // DOS 7.1 EBPB
    unsigned long FATsize_F32; // Число секторов, занятых одной FAT // [36, 39]
    unsigned int extFlags; // Двойное поле флагов (два одинаковых байтовых поля) // [40, 41]
    unsigned int FSversion; // Версия // [42, 43]
    unsigned long rootCluster; // Номер первого кластера, занимаемого корневым каталогом на FАТ32-диске // [44, 47]
    // FSinfo указывает на второй загрузочный сектор. В нём содержится информация о том,
    // сколько на диске всего кластеров, сколько из них свободно и какой кластер был выделен самым последним.
    // Таким образом, чтобы получить эту часто используемую информацию, теперь не нужно считывать всю таблицу FAT.
    unsigned int FSinfo; // Указывает на сектор FSinfo structure // [48, 49]
    unsigned int BackupBootSector; // Номер логического сектора, хранящий копию загрузочного // [50, 51]
    unsigned char reserved[12]; // Зарезервировано (имя файла загрузки) // [52, 63]
    unsigned char driveNumber; // Номер физического диска                       // 0x80 идентифицирует основной раздел // [64]
    unsigned char reserved1; // Флаги // [65]
    unsigned char bootSignature; // Расширенная загрузочная запись // [66]
    unsigned long volumeID; // Серийный номер тома // [67, 70]
    unsigned char volumeLabel[11]; // Метка тома // [71, 81]
    unsigned char fileSystemType[8]; // Тип файловой системы (12- или 16-разрядная) // [82, 89]

    unsigned char bootData[420]; // [90, 509]
    unsigned int bootEndSignature; // 0xAA55, т.е. последовательность байтов 0x55, 0xAA // [510, 511]
} BIOS_PARAMETER_BLOCK_STRUCTURE;
```